# Free/Inexpensive Software For Monitoring Software Usage on OS X

Tags: mac-osx

What options are there for free or inexpensive software to track software usage (launch count and usage duration) on Mac OS X?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I am very curious about your reasons for wanting it.

Comment: I work for a K12 organization that has upwards of one hundred supported apps on multiple platforms.  We are trying to get together a listing of how often these apps are used so we can try and get some of them off the supported apps list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to know what your purpose for this is.  Are you just tracking it on a single workstation where the primary user knows and wants to be tracked, or are you tracking it across a lab of workstations where users don't know they're being tracked?

If it's the former, then you might try [Onlife](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2006090811360690) (might be defunct), [Log Application Usage](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/LogApplicationUsage.shtml), or [myMacTime](http://www.pointworks.de/software/mymactime/index.php).

If it's the latter, you could use sLife (mentioned in another answer).  If you want a free, self-contained, and truly scalable solution, set up [Net-SNMP](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/) on your workstations.  You can query a list of running processes on the machine remotely using the prTable entries.  Some monitoring software, such as [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/), can track how many instances of certain processes are running at any given time (and how much processor load and memory they're using).  You could also write a simple script to query and tally the results in the format you need.

Comment: We are trying to track several labs of computers and some laptops.

Answer (score 0):

## sLife

WINDOWS AND MAC... sLife is pretty cool ([**Free**](https://www.slifeweb.com/registration.php?accountlevel=basic) [basic account]  and [**Open Source**](http://www.slifelabs.com/development)).  It logs the time spent on:

- Applications
- Websites (URLs)
- Documents

With a running application that securely uploads these info to your account on their [**website**](https://www.slifeweb.com/), which is [**"accessible by you and no one else"**](http://www.slifelabs.com/help).

The paid versions (Plus, Premium, and 'Teams Edition') include Unlimited data and backups, real-time activity tracking, privacy controls, visual analytics and technical support.

[alt text http://v4-slabs-assets.slifelabs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/home/sweb-screenshots.gif](http://v4-slabs-assets.slifelabs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/home/sweb-screenshots.gif)

Answer (score 0):

ManicTime (similar to sLife)

http://lifehacker.com/5154090/manictime-tracks-your-work-day

(But like sLife, it tracks the foreground application, not all of them)

Answer (score 0):

Remember your running on Unix now so the simplest and cheapest solution would be to write a shell script that logs a user's processes. Set it to run on log in and sample every 30 seconds or so. You can then process those logs into a format that is easy to read in spreadsheet.

I believe that Apple Remote Desktop has a logging function as well. If you don't have it, don't have the budget for it and you just need it for a short term project, contact your Apple Sales rep and see if you can't get a demo license. That would give you enough time to find out which apps you need.